# Output Page URL in Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

Using expression engine, trying to simply output the page's url to the page in text... will need to handle this conditionally; however, how does one simply get the `{page_url}` to appear on the page as text through the ee an site.group `footer.html` file?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the EE variable to display the full URL is {current_url}

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-url

Comment: Thanks, actually bypassed the template language and used raw PHP instead. Variables were already being defined in a top-level array, so through querying the request URI and tracing a variable, I was able to put through the right conditional, and perhaps more efficiently.